# union query only youngest result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have two query that are the same except for the two different tables `Transit_now` & `Transit_old`, both have the same layout. `Transit_old` is an archive of `transit_now`. Both querys will only display the youngest value

I only want the youngest value to display when i use a union  between the two querys. Now i have sometines two values from `transit_now` and `tansit_old`

Newest result can be in transit_old when there is no result for transit_now. There are multiple results on both tables, but that is coverd with the where statement in both querys

```sql
(
SELECT A.Batch, A.Date, B.name, B.Surname, 
FROM Transit_now
INNER JOIN DB.USERS B
ON A.Transit_now.ID = B.Users.ID
where A.DATE = (select MAX(DATE) from Transit_now where (A.Transit_now.ID = B.Users.ID))

UNION

SELECT A.Batch, A.Date, B.name, B.Surname, 
FROM Transit_old
INNER JOIN DB.USERS B
ON A.Transit_old.ID = B.Users.ID
where A.DATE = (select MAX(DATE) from Transit_now where (A.Transit_old.ID = B.Users.ID))
)
```

Comment: Your question needs more information.  Can the newest row be in `transit_old` if there is a row in `transit_new`?  Can there be duplicate rows in both tables?  Sample data and desired results often helps.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve]